# Postgres setting autocommit off globally

Tags: postgresql, transactions, autocommit

How do you set autocommit off in psql 8.4 at a global level? is there a configuration attribute that i can change that will introduce this behaviour for all dbs on a cluster to start db sessions with autocommit off?

Comment: There is no such configuration setting.

Comment: +1 for including PostgreSQL version. You don't turn autocommit off globally, you must `BEGIN` an explicit transaction if you don't want autocommit.

Answer (score 16):

Simply add the following to `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

Note that this only works when using the `psql` shell! I assume this is what you are talking about?

Answer (score 8):

Use a transaction if you want want a (open) transaction:

```
BEGIN;
  INSERT ...;
  UPDATE ...;
COMMIT; -- when you're done
```

Answer (score 1):

Like exhuma said, you can set it to off in your personal **~/.psqlrc** file.

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

But since you asked for a global level, the right file on Ubuntu is psqlrc (without leading dot) in **/etc/postgresql-common/**

To evaluate the right directory on your system, you may use:

```
pg_config --sysconfdir
```

There is a sample psqlrc-file in

```
/usr/share/postgresql/12/psqlrc.sample
```

(for Version 12, obviously) but it doesn't contain further information.

Locate it on your system with

```
locate psqlrc
```

I can't say, whether this information is valid for older versions than 12, but from my memory, it is, at least for the personal rc-file.