# JTA not rolling back when deleting cascade fails

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb, cascade, jta

Using: Glassfish 3.1.2, EclipseLink.

I have the following three-classes JPA model:

```
@Entity public class Customer implements Serializable {

@Id private Integer id;

@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval=true)
private Person person;
```

[...]

```
@Entity public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id private Integer id;
```

[...]

```
@Entity public class Request implements Serializable {

@Id private Integer id;

@ManyToOne private Person person;
```

I try to remove a customer with the following strategy (using **CMT**):

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>

        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>                  
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

[...]

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="MyPU")
private EntityManager entityManager;   

@Resource private SessionContext context;
```

[...]

```
public void delete(Entity object) {

    try{

        object = this.getEntityManager().merge(object);
        this.getEntityManager().remove(object);

    } catch (Exception e){

        this.context.setRollbackOnly();
    }
}
```

When the **Customer** object is attached to a **Person** object that is attached to a **Request**, the delete cascade of **Person** fails causing the transaction to rollback, but the **Customer** is **deleted** from the database. I receive the following error:

```
INFO: [EL Fine]: 2012-12-28 10:53:38.1--Connection(27132168)--DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [97]
INFO: [EL Fine]: 2012-12-28 10:53:38.125--Connection(27132168)--DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [111]
INFO: [EL Fine]: 2012-12-28 10:53:38.126--SELECT 1
WARNING: DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
Local Exception Stack:
INFO: [EL Warning]: 2012-12-28 10:53:38.127--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRO: atualização ou exclusão em tabela "person" viola restrição de chave estrangeira "fk_request_person_id" em "request"
Detalhe: Chave (id)=(111) ainda é referenciada pela tabela "request".
Error Code: 0
Call: DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [111]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(111)
[...]
SEVERE: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
[...]
```

So, how can i cancel the customer removal when the cascade deletion fails?

Comment: Is your DB connection set to autocommit, maybe? If not, please show us your transaction boundaries.

Comment: This may be the problem. I tested the application using an **Oracle 10g** connection, and the **rollback works** (i need the application to work with this two DB's - Oracle 10g and Postgres 8.4). The transaction is on a Stateless Bean, the boudary is **JTA's default** (REQUIRED). There is no way to disable Postgres 8.4 (wich i'm using) autocommit according to **this link**: _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837146/postgres-setting-autocommit-off-globally_. Maybe i'll have to use a bean-managed transaction?

Comment: With boundary I mean the beginning and the end of the transaction - anyway, if it works with Oracle, the problem is the DB (connection). Please post the setup for the connection.

Comment: Yes, i use annotations. I use a JTA connection pool with default attributes. Can you please be more specific about the connection setup?

Comment: Moved my comments into a real answer as this was getting longish.

Comment: In order to check what could be wrong with your Postgres DB connection, I would like to have some more details: what app server are you using, how did you configure the datasource, did you set any specific properties, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that possible may go wrong here.

- The transaction boundaries are not correctly specified

Maybe due to this, your application server does not issue the BEGIN statement correctly. This would explain that Postgres has a problem, while Oracle does not (it implicitly starts a transaction). Make sure your service methods wear the correct annotations. If everything is fine, maybe

- There is a problem with your datasource.

Is it a JTA compatible datasource? Does it use the correct driver for Postgres? Please post your config so that we can check out.

I found an interesting link that may help you as well. It is about Postgres staying in autocommit mode (although when using Spring):

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2007-07/msg00115.php

Comment: Using **defaultAutocommit = false** (as described on the link you post) on my JDBC Connection Pool Properties on Glassfish solved the problem. I'm with PostgreSQL 8.4.15 and postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar driver.

Comment: Ok, I'll adapt the answer so that it gets obvious the further readers what the solution was. Could you say which class you use? Simple our PoolableDatasource?