# Not using "begin transaction" and "commit" statements in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, transactions, commit, rdbms, rollback

Whenever I am accessing a PostgreSQL database with terminal I don't use "begin transaction" or "commit;" statements. Still, changes made by me on the database are permanent. (they don't get rollbacked when I turn off terminal). Why is it? Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837146/postgres-setting-autocommit-off-globally ; keyword you're looking for is "autocommit"

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy I did google search and basic research. I did not know what exactly to search on google.That is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default psql CLI interface runs in autocommit mode.
See https://dzone.com/articles/autocommit-in-postgresqls-psql